Exercise on finding probability density function
Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ by independent and uniformly distributed over the interval (0, 1). Find the probability density for $U = Y_1/Y_2$:
Solution:
$F_U(u) = P(U \le u) = P(Y_1/Y_2 \le u)$. Looking at the figure:

we can see that there are two regions: $0 \le u \le 1$ and $u \gt 1$. Because $tan(\alpha) = \frac{1}{u} = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$ we see that $u = y_1$, so either can say that $F_U(u) = \frac{y_1 y_2}{2} = \frac{u y_2}{2}$, because $y_2 = 1$, then $F_U(u) = \frac{u}{2}$ for $0 \le u \le 1$. So, $f_U(u) = \frac{d[F_U(u)]}{du} = \frac{1}{2}$ on this range.
Next, we need to find $f_U(u)$ when $u \gt 1$. To do it we need to find integral:
$$F_U(u) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{y_1/u}{\frac{1}{(\theta_2 - \theta_1)^2}dy_2 dy_1} = \frac{1}{2u}$$
because $\theta_2 = 1$ and $\theta_1 = 0$. So, differentiating this, gives negative result $f_U(u) = \frac{-1}{2u^2}$. This looks explainable, because $\frac{1}{2u}$ is a hyperbola and on $u \gt 1$ it's decreasing one, so derivative is negative, but from definition of density function it cannot be negative, obviously.
Answers for this are:
$$f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2}, 0 \le u \le 1$$
and
$$f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2u^2}, u \gt 1$$
I can't understand how $f_U(u)$ turned to be positive, please, help.

"Because $tg\alpha = \frac{1}{u} = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$ we see that $u = y_1$, " ... what does this mean?  What are $t$, $g$, and $\alpha$?  How did $y_2$ disappear in the final term?

@jbowman, $tg\alpha$ means "tangent" of angle $\alpha$, of adjacent to x-axis (actually $y_1$ in the figure) sorry, may be that still not fully correct, I'm not very familiar with english notation of trigonometric functions. Anyway, question isn't about the first part, it is rather about the 2nd one, where density function is negative

@jbowman, $y_2$ didn't disappear, it equals 1 (interval length $1 - 0 = 1$), so was omitted

Note that $F_U(u)$, as written, is a decreasing function of $u$, whereas cumulative density functions are nondecreasing functions of their arguments.  As $u \to \infty$, $F(u) \to 0$, instead of $1$ as it should. So that's the line I would focus on, as a hint.  No worries on the notation, btw; it's "tan" ("sin", "cos") in English.

I found a solution for my question (thanks to @Ben's answer). In the figure above I need to find $P(U \le u) = P(Y_1/Y_2 \le u)$. So, I need to find area above the line $u = Y_1/Y_2$. What I found $F_U(u) = \frac{1}{2u}$ is the area below the line (I have no idea why I decided that the $P(U \le u)$ is below the line), so the final distribution function for $u \gt 1$ must be $F_U(u) = 1 - \frac{1}{2u}$, because the whole area of the square is $1$. So, I can find correct density function $f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2u^2}$.

It is simpler to do this with a single integral (using the law of total probability) rather than a double integral.  For all $u>0$ we can write the distribution function as:
$$\begin{align}
F_U(u)
&\equiv \mathbb{P}(U \leqslant u) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(Y_1/Y_2 \leqslant u) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(Y_1 \leqslant u Y_2) \\[12pt]
&= \int \limits_0^1 \mathbb{P}(Y_1 \leqslant u Y_2|Y_2 = y) \cdot \text{U}(y|0,1) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^1 \mathbb{P}(Y_1 \leqslant u y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^1 \min(uy, 1) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^{\min(1,1/u)} uy \ dy + \int \limits_{\min(1,1/u)}^{1}  \ dy \\[12pt]
&= \frac{u}{2} \min(1,1/u)^2 + \max(0,1-1/u) \\[16pt]
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{u}{2} & & & \text{for } 0 \leqslant u \leqslant 1, \\[6pt]
\frac{u}{2} (1/u)^2 + (1-1/u) & & & \text{for } u > 1, \\[6pt]
\end{cases} \\[12pt]
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{u}{2} & & & \text{for } 0 \leqslant u \leqslant 1, \\[6pt]
1-\frac{1}{2u} & & & \text{for } u > 1, \\[6pt]
\end{cases} \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$
so the density function is:
$$f_U(u)
= \frac{dF_U}{du}(u) 
= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & & & \text{for } 0 \leqslant u \leqslant 1, \\[6pt]
\frac{1}{2u^2} & & & \text{for } u > 1. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

Oh, man, I got it... I need an area above the line, but I calculated that is below the line, so answer is opposite, I.e. $1 - F_U(u)$
